# Как распарсить(десерилизовать) разные JSON в один класс на Java используя Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть несколько Json'ов(на самом деле около сотни).

```
{"error":[],
  "result":{
    "ONE":[
      ["text11","text12",1],
      ["text21","text22",2],
      ..
    ],
    "time": "150213764494537"}
}
```

и

```
{"error":[],
  "result":{
    "TWO":[
      ["text11","text12",1],
      ["text21","text22",2],
      ..
    ],      
    "time": "150213764494537"}
}
```

Они отличаются на имена массивов (`ONE`, `TWO`). Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку `Gson`. Я понял как парсить создав для каждого такого Json'а отдельные классы.

Сейчас у меня есть 2 пары классов и 2 разных вызова:

```
gson.fromJson(json, ResponseOne.class).getResult().getONE()
gson.fromJson(json, ResponseTwo.class).getResult().getTWO()
```

Хочется это парсить весть этот зоопарк в один класс универсально, подскажите можно ли это как то реализовать с использованием библиотеки `Gson` ?
Чтобы получалось что-то в духе:

```
gson.fromJson(json, ResponseOneOrTwo.class).getResult().getONEorTWO()
```

**PS**

К сожалению я не могу управлять способом формирования этих Json'ов. Я обречен страдать и парсить их так.

Comment: Вариантов много, зависит от того, как эти данные потом будут обрабатываться. Можно вообще не париться с классами и работать с чистым `JsonObject`. Можно написать несколько классов, в одном из которых будет поле `HashMap<String, Data>`

Comment: Я хочу просто загнать эти Json'ы в один объект, из которого мог бы доставать массивы однообразным способом. Вместо `gson.fromJson(json, Response.class).getResult().getONE()` что нибудь в духе `gson.fromJson(json, Response.class).getResult().getONorTWO()`

Comment: Правда ли, что из всего json-а нужен только массив, который находится по ключу `one` или `two`? Что насчёт получения `JsonObject` (`new JsonParser().parse(json_string)`), затем из этого `JsonObject` извлечение этого массива, примерно так: `jsonObject.get("result").values()[0]`

Comment: Нужны все объекты, которые есть. Просто со всем, кроме массива понятно, как получить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно описать свой десериалайзер и использовать его при десериализации всех json'ов такого типа.
Пример:
`Example` - класс в который будет происходить десериализация

```
package jsons;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 12.10.2017.
 */
public class Example {
    private List<String> error = new ArrayList();
    private List<ArrayList<String>> oneOrTwo = new ArrayList();
    private String time;

    public List<String> getError() { return error;}

    public List<ArrayList<String>> getOneOrTwo() { return oneOrTwo; }

    public String getTime() { return time;}

    public void setTime(String time){ this.time = time; }

    public void addOneOrTwo(ArrayList<String> element){ oneOrTwo.add(element);}

    public void addError(String error){this.error.add(error);}
}
```

`ExampleDeserializer` - класс, описывающий алгоритм десериализации

```
package jsons;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Example> {

    @Override
    public Example deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        Example example = new Example();
        JsonObject jObject1 = json.getAsJsonObject();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jObject1.entrySet()) {
            switch (entry.getKey()) {
                case "error":
                    if (!entry.getValue().isJsonNull()) {
                        for (JsonElement error : entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray()) {
                            example.addError(error.getAsString());
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case "result":
                    if (!entry.getValue().isJsonNull()) {
                        JsonObject jObject2 = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry2 : jObject2.entrySet()) {
                            switch (entry2.getKey()) {
                                case "time":
                                    example.setTime(entry2.getValue().getAsString());
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    for (JsonElement jElement : entry2.getValue().getAsJsonArray()) {
                                        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for (JsonElement jElement2 : jElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
                                            list.add(jElement2.getAsString());
                                        }
                                        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                                            example.addOneOrTwo(list);
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
        return example;
    }
}
```

не забыть заригистрировать свой десериалайзер

```
Gson gson2 = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Example.class, new ExampleDeserializer()).create();
```

десериализовать можно так

```
System.out.println(gson2.fromJson(json3, Example.class).getOneOrTwo().toString());
```

Comment: Сильно помогла статья с хабра https://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/

Answer (score 2):

Если будут встречаться только строки `ONE` и `TWO`, можно создать класс, в котором будет в том числе два поля с именами `ONE` и `TWO`. Соответственно при десериализации будет заполняться один из этих двух полей и нужный можно будет получить, взяв ненулевое поле:

```
class Result {
    Data ONE:
    Data TWO:

    getONEOrTWO() {
        return ONE != null ? ONE : TWO;
    }
}
```

---

Если строк-ключей может быть много, то можно вместо создания этого класса использовать `Map<String, Data>`. Соответственно при десериализации в этой `HashMap` должен быть один ключ и одно значение.

```
class Response {
    Map<String, Data> result;

    getONEOrTWO() {
        return result.values().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению вариантов того, что может встретиться около сотни и новые варианты могут не контролируемо добавляться без всяких уведомлений об этом. Поясните пож, как работает второй вариант(с `Map)`. Немножко не въехал

Comment: Похоже, что должен подойти, с утра завтра проверю